# What are the effects of smoking in the first week of pregnancy?

Tags: obstetrics, smoking, irreversible-damage, fetus, 1st-trimester

If I'm 1 week pregnant and I've been smoking everyday since then how did that effect the fetus? And if there's like any damage how can i fix my mistake?

Comment: It's not a fetus yet.  You still have time to quit.  Go see your doctor, to get some practical support for maximizing your health and your baby's.

Answer (score 2):

You are still very early in your pregnancy, so it is likely that everything will be fine if you take measures to stop smoking now.  I would highly suggest meeting with your OBGYN to discuss safe methods for smoking cessation during pregnancy.  The earlier you quit, the better off your baby's development will be.  Prenatal smoking has been associated with premature births, low-birthweight, as well as behavioral problems throughout childhood and adolescence.  It is important to note, however, that the severity of these effects depend on a number of factors, including length of time the mother smoked while pregnant, how much she smoked while pregnant, as well as other health-related issues of the mother.  Early intervention to stop smoking, as well as comprehensive prenatal care for both you and your baby are very important.  But again, it is still very early in your pregnancy, so with proper healthcare, it is likely that all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix it, but you *can* prevent further harm

I disagree with Prince's second assertion; broken waters do not necessarily need immediate delivery, Peri-natal kept my partner going for a few weeks until she hit week 34, following broken waters at week 31, for developmental reasons.   Its still serious, expensive (three weeks in hospital isn't cheap) and best avoided for all concerned.

I'm not suggesting however that you should continue smoking **at all**. It can lead to low birth weight, premature delivery or both (as was true in my own case as a baby)

Comment: I agree with your disagreement, but the fact that broken waters means immediate delivery are for some mothers, since everyone has a different anatomy. But thanks for your observation that it doesn't apply to everyone.

Comment: We require all awnsers on Health SE to be referenced.  Please see this [meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers/103#103) for additional details.

Comment: **Just delete me**, I answered on the basis of my personal experience in an effort to assist, in five free minutes at work. I don't have the leeway to sit and find references for _everything_ I write what with having to work and all, so just delete me from this forum. Its frankly too much trouble to be worthwhile. Enjoy your victory.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, an embryo is not susceptible to maternal exposures for the 1st 21 days (day 1 being conception) and then considered most susceptible (depending on the threat / insult) from day 22 through day 72.  When one considers timing issues in early pregnancy, be aware the due date is historically based on the 1st day of the last menstrual period which about 2 weeks before the actual concepticon.  Fetus most vulnerable between 3 to 8 weeks after conception which corresponds with being between 5 to 10 weeks pregnant based on last period. Embryologist vs Obstetrical age/dates. In the old days, there weren't ovulation predictors or early ultrasound - 1st day of the last menstrual period was the only "landmark"  for predicting the due date.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). You provide interesting information, but it is a policy on Health that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), since they are the only way for the community to assess the merit of an answer, regardless of the reader's background. You can always [edit] your answer to add references. Thanks!